# How can I constantly check if a JSON file is updated in Python? - discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py

hi i am trying to implement a money system in my discord.py bot but when the bot creates a account for the user it dont updates constantly and i need to restart the bot to check if there is a account for the user. i wanna know how to update the json file constantly in python. my code:

```
f = open('MainBank.json')
banks = json.load(f)

client = discord.Client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">", case_insensitive=True)

@client.command()
async def bal(ctx):
    if f"{ctx.author.id}" in banks:
        print("-_-")
    else:
        user_detail = {f'{ctx.author.id}': [{'wallet':10, 'bank': 10}]}
        with open("MainBank.json", "r+") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            data.update(user_detail)
            file.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, file)

    

    wallet_amt = banks[f'{ctx.author.id}'][0]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = banks[f'{ctx.author.id}'][0]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance")
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    earnings = random.randrange(150)
    banks[f'{ctx.author.id}'][0]["wallet"]+=earnings
    with open('MainBank.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(banks, file)
    await ctx.send(f"Someone gave you {earnings}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check for the user account, you use the `banks` variable, which you only set once at the start of your code and never update afterwards. This means any changes you make to the file will not be reflected in `banks`.

You need to do something similar as your `else` statement where you load the json file before checking if the user account is in it.

```
...
@client.command()
async def bal(ctx):
    with open("MainBank.json", "r+") as file:
        data = json.load(file) 
    if f"{ctx.author.id}" in data:
        print("-_-")
    else:
        user_detail = {f'{ctx.author.id}': [{'wallet':10, 'bank': 10}]}
        with open("MainBank.json", "r+") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            data.update(user_detail)
            file.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, file)
...
```